# How to upload MultipartFile in htmlunit?

Tags: spring-mvc, webclient, htmlunit, webrequest, multipartfile

I am using HtmlUnit to upload a file by making a request to the spring controller. The file is of type MultipartFile.
Using the below code works only for File Type java.io.File. How do i make the call for MultipartFile?

WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("/customer/uploadfile),POST);

request.setRequestParameters(toList(new KeyDataPair("newfile", file,"customerfile", "multipart/form-data", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

Comment: Show your controller code. You can transform MultipartFile to File and then issue the call.

Comment: public ModelAndView uploadCustomerFile(ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes redirect,
   @ModelAttribute MultipartFile file, 
   ) { }   I can't change the multipartfile to file. The method should have Multipartfile.